# Grouping by two fields in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am attempting to get a count of records created on each day for the last 15 days.  I came up with the query below:

```
db.users.aggregate(
    {   $group: {   
            _id: {$dayOfYear: '$created'},
            created: {$sum:1},
            date: {$first: '$created'}
        }
    },
    {$sort: {_id: 1}},
    {$limit: 15}
);
```

Which almost works, but it will also count days from exactly a year ago.  So if 2 records were created on 2/20/2014 and 3 were created on 2/20/2013 then a count of 5 would be returned (when all I want is 2).  I was hoping to also group by the year like below:

```
db.users.aggregate(
    {   $group: {   
            _id: {{$dayOfYear: '$created'},{$year: '$created'}},
            created: {$sum:1},
            date: {$first: '$created'}
        }
    },
    {$sort: {_id: 1}},
    {$limit: 15}
);
```

But this is a syntax error.  How should I be attempting to count records created on a specific day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.users.aggregate(
    { $group: {   
            _id: {
                day: { $dayOfYear: '$created' },
                year: { $year: '$created' }
            },
            count: { $sum: 1 },
            date: { $first: '$created' }
        }
    },
    { $project: { _id: 0, date: 1, count: 1 } }, // Only for more clear result.
    { $sort: { date: -1 } }, // If you want to view last 15 days - sort by descending.
    { $limit: 15 }
);
```